# Can I change a string in the strings resource file to one from array in an activity?

Tags: android

Been having a little bit of trouble with this. Googled about and I can't really find anything. Saw a few things about setting text but I don't think that affects the string resource file or at least I can't make it affect the resource file. Help please!

Comment: Why do u want to change the string resource file? Instead use setText("") where ever you want to change the string value.

Comment: Got a parallel array set up set up to change the people according to shifts. So if it's Monday I want person x displayed, Tuesday, person y, etc etc.

Comment: Then go for Switch Statements for time saving. For Example: Weekends in one array calledso weekarray() and persons in another array calledso personarray(). Then Switch it according to weekarray(). Hopeso you got it i said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't modify apk at the runtime. If you don't own source code, you can pull apk file to the computer and decompile it by using APKTool, for example. If you are working with data you get from internet/user, it should be kept inside DBs, files, whatever. In other words in internal or external storage. Please take a look on storage options you can use http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html